# How to prove that a $d$-dimensional Hilbert space can only have $d^2$ equiangular vectors (i.e. that a SIC is a maximal collection of that kind)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information

It is an open question if every $d$-dimensional Hilbert space contains a collection of $d^2$ states, such that for every two of them the squared absolute value of the scalar product is equal to $\frac{1}{d+1}$, i.e. if a SIC-POVM exists for every dimension.

However, I don't understand why $d^2$ is the ultimate upper bound for the size of such a collection. The papers I've seen so far (for example, [this review article](https://www.mdpi.com/2075-1680/6/3/21)) just mention that it can be proven, but don't go into detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one answer in [this paper](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/conference-proceedings-of-spie/5914/1/Complex-equiangular-tight-frames/10.1117/12.618821.short?SSO=1). Let $S$ be the $d \times N$ matrix whose columns are the SIC vectors, and let $G = S^\dagger S$ be their Gram matrix. The rank of $G$ is equal to $d$ unless the vectors live in a proper subspace of $\mathbb{C}^d$. Now, consider the matrix $G \cdot G^T$ where the dot means the entrywise product of matrices (aka Hadamard product). This matrix has ones on the main diagonal and identical terms $|\langle \psi_i | \psi_j \rangle|^2 < 1$ in all off-diagonal elements. The rank of this matrix is $N$.

The crucial trick is that the rank of the Hadamard product is less or equal than product of ranks of the matrices:

$$
N = \operatorname{rank}(G \cdot G^T) \leq \operatorname{rank}(G) \operatorname{rank}(G^T) = d^2.
$$